# What does "provided->default" mean in an sbt build file?

Tags: sbt

An example of this comes from a [sample github project](https://github.com/ggarciajr/slick/blob/master/build.sbt):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default",
...
}
```

I'm only vaguely clear on what the 'fourth column' in these configurations mean, but this is the first time I've seen either `provided` or `provided->default`, and it's unclear how I can go about finding what should be expected here in the documentation. Can anyone help explain this construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your `provided` configuration depends on the `default` configuration of `"java.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5"`.

[Maven scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) describe what these configurations or scopes mean.

For instance, if you're using a library to write your tests, you've probably come across something like `"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.2" % "test"` or similar. Here, the second part of the configuration is omitted and refers to the `default` configuration (usually `compile`). Equivalently, you could write `"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.2" % "test->compile"`. It means that your `test` configuration depends on the `default` configuration of ScalaCheck: your tests need ScalaCheck on the class path to compile and run.

You may find more details in the [Ivy documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/conf.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the cascade of dependency yet, but it's helpful to know this is a Maven scope thing for more reading. The Ivy link was useful too! Thanks!